# Error trying to modify a specific macro

Tags: macros

After `\show\orientador` I get this output:

```
> \orientador=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \orientador \\orientador {Orientador:\vspace {1mm}\\}.
```

I wanna change the word "Orientador" to "Advisor":

```
\renewcommand\orientador{\@protected@testopt \orientador \\orientador {Advisor:\vspace {1mm}\\}}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
! You can't use `spacefactor' in vertical mode.\@->\spacefactor\@m {} \orientador
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \orientador
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `\show\orientador` is characteristic of a macro defined with an optional argument.

The definition is, quite likely,

```
\newcommand{\orientador}[2][Orientador:\vspace{1mm}\\]{#1#2}
```

(with possibly more structure in the replacement text).

You don't need to modify the macro, just call it like

```
\orientador[Advisor:\vspace{1mm}\\]{Prof. A. N. Advisor}
```